# Trying to compare elements of string with loops and indices, but indices do not increment

Tags: c++, string

I am trying to make a Su Doku solver for Euler Project.  I am having trouble comparing string elements.   My 2nd loop with index k occurs only once, rather than nine times. if I remove the code with my if statement, it loops through just fine.  Anyone know why?  Something about trying to access my strings makes it stop...

`puzzle` is a vector and `reference_string`is a string `="123456789"`.

```
for (int i = 0; i != 9; i++){
    cout << "loop 1" << endl;
    for (int k = 0; k != 9; k++) {

        if (reference_string[i] == puzzle[row_index][k] || 
            reference_string[k] == puzzle[col_index][k] || 
             reference_string[i] == puzzle[box_index][k] ){
            possible_answers.push_back(0);
        }

        else if ( k = 8 ){
            possible_answers.push_back(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change `k = 8` to `k == 8`, or safer `8 == k`.  You are not performing a comparison, you are performing an assignment that alters the loop counter so the loop condition is satisfied after just one iteration.

Comment: Oh, great thanks! I missed that.  I just spotted one other error now for the second line in the conditional.  That should be an i.  I guess I am tired because i have been searching for the mistake for a while now.  But it works just as I want it now.  :)

Comment: Did your compiler try to warn you about the erroneous assignment?  Some compilers do warn about a *suspicious* assignment if you perform an assignment inside of an `if` statement (there are legitimate cases for doing that, which is why it is only a warning and not an error, but I don't like code that relies on that).